# Python bar chart with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=[1, 0, 0, 1],
    B=[0, 1, 1, 1],
    C=[1, 0, 0, 0]
))
```

How to plot a barplot where I sea number of 1s and 0s in one graph see:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the dataset you provided:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=[1, 0, 0, 1],
    B=[0, 1, 1, 1],
    C=[1, 0, 0, 0]
))
```

you should re-shape the dataframe with [**`pandas.melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
df = pd.melt(frame = df,
             var_name = 'class',
             value_name = 'survived')
```

```
   class  survived
0      A         1
1      A         0
2      A         0
3      A         1
4      B         0
5      B         1
6      B         1
7      B         1
8      C         1
9      C         0
10     C         0
11     C         0
```

So you can use [**`seaborn.countplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) to get the plot you want:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.countplot(ax = ax, data = df, x = 'class', hue = 'survived')

plt.show()
```

### Complete Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=[1, 0, 0, 1],
    B=[0, 1, 1, 1],
    C=[1, 0, 0, 0]
))

df = pd.melt(frame = df,
             var_name = 'class',
             value_name = 'survived')


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.countplot(ax = ax, data = df, x = 'class', hue = 'survived')

plt.show()
```

[image]